# "Talk" by Hozier, meaning

Tags: lyrics, meaning

In Hozier's song "Talk" he sings "[That's found in the last witness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pe0X5krc40M&t=2m0s) /
Before the wave hits / marveling at God / Before he feels alone one final time and marries the sea." I know song use the Greeks mythology but I can't relate to what I know.

What does "last witness" refers to and what "wave" he means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the first verse of the song refers to the Greek myth of [Orpheus and Eurydice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orpheus_and_Eurydice), the second verse refers to the Christian [biblical Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Revelation). The Book of Revelation refers to [Two Witnesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_witnesses) who appear during the [Second Woe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_trumpets#Sixth_trumpet), a "wave" of attack by God's army.

Please note that I am not able to find a discussion of "Talk"'s lyrics to confirm or refute these conclusions.